# How to sort an inverted dictionary with non-unique values?

Tags: python, dictionary

So for my problem, I have to take a provided dictionary with non-unique values that counts word frequencies and invert it.

My problem is that I don't know how to sort the values in alphabetical order (ex. 1: ['jump', 'jam'] needs to be sorted so it shows 1:['jam', 'jump'] where 'jump' and 'jam' both appear once in the provided dictionary) I have code for inverting the dictionary, but the values are unsorted.

```
def inverted_word_counts(word_count_dict): 
    inverted_dict = {}
    for key, value in word_count_dict.items():
        inverted_dict.setdefault(value, list()).append(key) 
    return inverted_dict
```

Comment: Can you provide your input data and sample output?

Comment: `sorted` will sort strings in alphabetical (read: lexicographical) order.

Comment: Comparing two strings will automatically sort them per letter basis. So 'jam' is less than 'jump' because a < u 

the example you provided is also for a list and not a dictionary

Comment: Sorting a list is covered quite well in the available documentation.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: input dictionary:      {'bug': 2, 'jump':1, 'jam':1}        and the expected is:            {2: ['bug'], 1: ['jam', jump]}       but what i get is jump in front of jam, not sorted alphabetically

Comment: Iterate over the values of the inverted dictionary. Sort each value (which is a list).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/bisect.html) module to insert your new values while maintaining the sort order. This can be more efficient than sorting at the end and much more efficient than sorting in each loop iteration.

For example:

```
import bisect

d = {'dog':20, 'darn':20, 'dirg':20, 'apple':10, 'zebra':10,'cat':10}

def inverted_word_counts(word_count_dict): 
    inverted_dict = {}
    for key, value in word_count_dict.items():
        bisect.insort(inverted_dict.setdefault(value, list()), key)
    return inverted_dict

inverted_word_counts(d)

# {20: ['darn', 'dirg', 'dog'], 10: ['apple', 'cat', 'zebra']}
```